Ubuntu on snapdragon laptop
I am considering on buying Dell's XPS-13 with snapdragon CPU.
I was wondering if the linux kernel supports snapdragon CPU. Any information/useful link would be appreciated.

wouldn't it be simpler to ask Dell if their product will support the Linux kernel?

From what I read, everything does not work yet for Linux with these Snapdragon Elite X laptops. Here is an example: https://www.tomshardware.com/pc-components/cpus/snapdragon-x-elite-igpu-disabled-by-default-in-latest-linux-patch-caused-by-oem-key-signing-that-may-not-be-available

Qualcomm made an experimental Debian image available See https://www.qualcomm.com/developer/blog/2024/05/upstreaming-linux-kernel-support-for-the-snapdragon-x-elite and https://git.codelinaro.org/linaro/qcomlt/demos/debian-12-installer-image

This question is similar to: Can you install Ubuntu on a Snapdragon PC?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

As of this date, there is kernel support but general support for other hardware components is not there yet. The Ubuntu people have proposed a "concept image" of 24.10 and work is active on several popular laptops with the new chip. There is an issue capturing progress on support for the XPS-13 in particular

Thank you so much for the information! Do you know if there is anyway to donate, create issues (git), or contribute to this project?

@Tom I'm not involved, just following along like you. I guess you could reply to the issue on launchpad.net asking the same question.
